# Java - how do you find out which class file has a corrupt constant pool?

Tags: java, constants, javac, pool

Is there some kind of a tool or some better output from `javac` to figure out which class file has a corrupt constant pool.. as I cannot compile some existing java files due to some pre-compiled file has a corrupt constant pool..

Here is how a corrupt constant pool stack print out looks like

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.6.0_26). Please file a bug at the J
ava Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking
 the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnosti
c in your report.  Thank you.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8047705
        at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.nextInt(ClassReader.java:277)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.skipMember(ClassReader.java:1504)

        at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:1559)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readClassFile(ClassReader.java:16
58)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.fillIn(ClassReader.java:1845)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.complete(ClassReader.java:1777)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:386)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:763)

        at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.loadClass(ClassReader.java:1951)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.loadClass(Resolve.java:842)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findIdentInPackage(Resolve.java:1011
)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.selectSym(Attr.java:1921)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:1835)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1522
)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:360)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribType(Attr.java:390)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.attribImportType(MemberEnter.jav
a:681)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.visitImport(MemberEnter.java:545
)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCImport.accept(JCTree.java:495)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:387
)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:399
)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.visitTopLevel(MemberEnter.java:5
12)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:
446)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:387
)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.complete(MemberEnter.java:819)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:386)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:763)

        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:464)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.complete(JavaCompiler.java:659)

        at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.fillIn(ClassReader.java:1869)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.complete(ClassReader.java:1777)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:386)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:763)

        at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.loadClass(ClassReader.java:1951)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.loadClass(Resolve.java:842)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findGlobalType(Resolve.java:901)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findType(Resolve.java:957)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findIdent(Resolve.java:986)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.resolveIdent(Resolve.java:1162)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitIdent(Attr.java:1714)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIdent.accept(JCTree.java:1547)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:360)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribType(Attr.java:390)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.signature(MemberEnter.java:355)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.visitMethodDef(MemberEnter.java:
560)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:639)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:387
)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:399
)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.finishClass(MemberEnter.java:410
)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.finish(MemberEnter.java:1000)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.complete(MemberEnter.java:967)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:386)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:763)

        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:464)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:442)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:81
9)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:727)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:279)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:270)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:69)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:54)
```

Comment: "Please file a bug" please do everyone else a favor and file a bug with Oracle/Sun, so this can be fixed in future versions too :)

Comment: not possible, nor even worth it.. many people already filled this bug all closed due to the fact, they don't want to support bad class files. Btw I fixed it by decompiling the class.. then recompiling it all is fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kinda fixed, found out a good quickfix.. just add `-verbose` to your `javac` parameters and you'll see like..

```
[parsing started .\a.java]
[parsing completed 0ms]
[loading .\ajava]
[parsing started .\b.java]
[parsing completed 0ms]
[loading .\bingo\foo.class] //<- here we go.. just before exception.

An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.6.0_26). Please file a bug at the J
ava Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking
 the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnosti
c in your report.  Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you instrument the compiler with aspectj.  You just need to trap that precise stack signatures and dump the params passed to each method.  Your class name is gonna be in that dump.

edit:

e.g. `com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readClassFile`

Comment: /grin Of course before all that read the javadocs for the tool classes and make sure either a path or class name at some point is on the stack.  Haven't looked myself but would expect to find something like that.

Comment: thats a good idea too i was about to resort to running javac in debugger haha and stepping through assembly code

Comment: actually why not debugger?  haven't tried myself but you do have a precise java method you want to set a breakpoint on.  readClassFile.

Comment: I was joking I meant a x86 debugger.. I know it's possible with some kind of java agent to attach to javac while it's running for like 10 seconds? and interrupt it somehow.. but that would require programming, I wanted some quick method so I can be done with this.. without wasting too much time.